# Formatting / adjusting incoming string to R

Tags: r, string, list, vector

I'm having trouble doing some extraction & coercing of a string in R. I'm not very good with R... just enough to be dangerous. Any help would be appreciated.

I am trying to take a string of this form:

`"AAA,BBB,CCC'`

And create two items:

1. A list containing each element separately (i.e. 3 entries) - `c("AAA","BBB","CCC")`.  I've tried `strsplit(string, ",")` but I get a list of length 1
2. A data frame with names = lower case entries, values = entries. e.g. `df = data.frame(aaa=AAA, bbb=BBB, ccc=CCC)`. I'm not sure how to pull out each of the elements, and lowercase the references.

Hopefully this is doable with R.  Appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string is malformed read in with quotes changed

```
malform <- read.table("weirdstring.txt", colClasses='character',quote = "")
str = gsub("\'|\"", "", malform[1,1])
```

The string should now look like:

```
str = "AAA,BBB,CCC"

## as list
ll <- unlist(strsplit(str, ","))

## df
df <- data.frame(t(ll))
names(df) <- sapply(ll, tolower)
```

Comment: The malformed quotes was a typo on my part. The rest of what you put there seems to work perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: actually maybe not quite. The data frame needs to reference existing objects AAA and BBB, not the strings themselves. Is this possible?

Comment: I figured it out (apologies for the lack of info!) - I copied your approach for lowercasing and got it working with this: `sapply(ll, get)` . Accepted your answer as you got me 99% of the way there.